# Excel values don't update on particular PC

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook which contains links to 4 other files.
In order to update the values I wrote the below:

It works perfect - values get updated correctly unless I run it on one particular PC. I checked the excel version and make sure all windows updates have been run.
Any ideas (or a different method) would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Refresh()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\C:\folder\file1.CSV")
    Workbooks.Open ("\\C:\folder\file2.CSV")
    Workbooks.Open ("\\C:\folder\file3.CSV")
    Workbooks.Open ("\\C:\folder\file4.xlsx")
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Windows("File1.CSV").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows("File2.CSV").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows("File3.CSV").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows("File4.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You should really use `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` rather than `ThisWorkbook.Activate` followed by `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Comment: First thing in my mind: either those files don't exist or you don't have access to the referred directory.

Comment: You also need to turn `Application.ScrrenUpdating` back on. I'm surprised it worked on any computers. Make sure that computer has `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`.